# behat selenium server clicking browser back button without waiting for page inside iframe to load

Tags: asynchronous, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

Here is my function code:

```
$this->getSession()->switchToIFrame("test-frame");
$page = $this->getSession()->getpage();
$page->fillField("name", "Test user");
$page->selectFieldOption("month", "01");
$page->selectFieldOption("year", $currentdate + 1);
$page->fillField("date", "01");
$page->pressButton("Save");
$this->getSession()->wait(7000);
$page->pressButton("Authenticate");
```

In my browser page there is iframe which loads a form. Post "Save" it goes to another page having "Authenticate" button. After clicking "Authenticate" button it goes to "Waiting..." page and redirect to browser with completion page. I want to hit browser back button after "Authenticate" but before "waiting..." page get fully loaded.
Default behat/mink is loading "waiting..." page and then hit browser back button which I don't want.

Is there any way to tell selenium webdriver to click browser back button without waiting for "waiting..." to get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
driver.navigate().back();
```

or

```
driver.navigate().forward();
```

Comment: how can i get driver object in behat/mink?

Comment: See Nirbhay Patil's Answer

Answer (score 0):

$this->getSession()->getDriver()

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/behat/back$20button/behat/JNspUmZ9gio/FRSZWhwMi-AJ

Comment: According to my knowledge here is the sequence of execution in behat
jscript(history.back()) > php > behat > ming > selenium driver api > selenium webdriver > browser
So is there any way I can directly access selenium drive api and execute browser back button.

Comment: IMHO please read this http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_migrating_from_rc_to_webdriver.jsp#waitforpagetoload-returns-too-soon. Therefore if you are using  page load has completed or not as event to fire another action i.e. back button, may be not produce correct result.